# Best Migration tool for magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to migrate data from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x. So which one is the best method or tool to migrate data. I am working on Magento 2.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this migration by using [this tool](https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases).

This tool migrates all data like customer, catalog-categories and products, orders and all other data in Magento 1.x.x to 2.0.x by simply specifying necessary data like Server and DB Details. You can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jvr8d3OeB8M&feature=youtu.be).

Eventhough This tool migrates some data, we have to manually migrate these data [check here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-manually.html)

Comment: I used this tool. But I got some problems.firstly this tool is compatible with magento 2.0. You can see they have given in description. any how when I used this tool. I migrate data successfully. But I got some issues with it that are single post page is not opening, also homepage showing some errors. and also on backend when I go to edit a single product which I migrate from magento 1.9, It show blank data in the edit page.

Comment: you add the product attributes..

Comment: you re indexing the site

Comment: Yes I reindex the site by using following command
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: How to add product attributes? The tool import all the attributes automatically !

Comment: you deploy static content  and clear the catch..

Comment: in migrate the tool ask the extra attributes to add.

Comment: Yes I did all that

Comment: On home page I got this error
"We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email."

Comment: and give the permission the var folder 777

Comment: send screenshot link

Comment: This is the screenshot from back end where all the catalog are showing. 
http://prnt.sc/dula8s
when I go to edit one of them then it shows a blank feild page. see screenshot
http://prnt.sc/dul9ux

Comment: On front end when I want to open a single product. It shows 404 page

Comment: in `var` folder clear the `generation` , `page_cache` and  `view_preprocessed` ... and clear the catch

Comment: I did, But still on the same problem.